# How to put read and cast into a char array

Tags: java

I have a source txt file and I am trying to read the characters using the .read() method of the FileReader class. I have got the integer values that come out the .read and cast them to char and looped the output to check this is working. The problem is that when I try to store them in an array, the array prints empty.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReversedQuotation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        char[] charArray = new char[1000];
        char[] sortedQuote = new char[1000];
        int counter = 999;
        int secondCounter = 0;
        FileReader fr = null;
    
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("/Users/cal/Desktop/backwards.txt");
            while(true) {
                try {
                
                    int charInt = fr.read();
                    if(charInt == -1) break;
                    charArray[counter] = (char)charInt;
                    counter--;
                    System.out.print(charArray[counter]);
                    System.out.print((char)charInt); // just to check the characters are                correct.
                    charArray[counter] = sortedQuote[secondCounter];
                    secondCounter++;
                    System.out.print(sortedQuote[secondCounter]);
                }
             catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IO Error in reading document");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error finding document.");
        } finally {
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error in closing the File Reader.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `charArray[counter] = sortedQuote[secondCounter];`, you are never writing to that array, therefore your existing values are null. And why are you making it so hard, and just not write to one array?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, the text in the file is written backwords and I am trying to put the text into a char array from the end of the array, then transfer the array into a new array from the start of the array so the text is now the right way round.

Comment: You can still do it with just one array, just don't use the `sortedQuote` array. You are already writing the char positions in reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

```
 charArray[counter] = (char)charInt; // say counter = 999
 counter--;
 System.out.print(charArray[counter]); // charArray[998]
```

This will print the value at *decremented* index(which is essentially empty) and not the *assigned* index.

```
 charArray[counter] = (char)charInt;
 System.out.print(charArray[counter]);
 counter--;
```

This should print what you have assigned.

**Second:**
`sortedQuote[secondCounter]` is never assigned and 
`charArray[counter] = sortedQuote[secondCounter]` assignment seems to have no purpose.